# Передача переменных POST GET

Tags: php

здравствуйте, вообщем такое дело, есть race.php там написал код который вытащит случайного пользователя из базы данных, и есть кнопка гонка , при нажатии нужно отыслать скорость машины ,как лучще его отправить hidden не катит! как передать скорость подскажите!!!

Comment: чем хидден не угодил

Comment: когда в исходном коде меняешь значение то это значение передается, а мне нужно сравнить ведь 
if($speed > $speed_vs){
echo "Победа";
}else{
if($speed < $speed_vs{
echo "Поражение";
}
}

Comment: увы не смогли помочь ((

Comment: а зачем отправлять скорость машины через клиента ? запоминайте какая машина будет участвовать в гонке (например в сессии) и считайте себе результат.

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понятна задача. В частности — зачем отправлять скорость POST-запросом, если пользователю запрещено её изменять? Скорее всего, вы что-то делаете не так.

Если я правильно понял, то вы выбираете случайную машину из базы, показываете эту скорость пользователю, и потом при нажатии на кнопку "гонка", эту же самую скорость опять отправляете и сравниваете с какой-то другой скоростью. Правильно? Если так, то вам ничего отправлять не надо, получили машину из базы, взяли её скорость и сравнили сразу со скоростью которая нужна.

Если же я ошибаюсь, то вам поможет сохранение скорости в сессию, либо можно просто зашифровать строку с скоростью и передать через hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ из комментария:

Запоминайте, какая машина будет участвовать в гонке (например, в сессии), и считайте результат.